# select columns from SQL table with more than X number of NON-NULL values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-null

I have a LOT of junk columns in my table containing thousands of null values and maybe one or two real values. I would like to select only the columns in this table containing more than 10 non-null values.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question here - what is stopping you from accomplishing the stated requirement? What problem do you have with your existing query / research?

Comment: There's no built in `SELECT WHERE BUNCH OF STUFF IS NOT NULL`. You need to do your own select operation, like `SELECT CASE x IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE ... END` and establish some kind of threshold.

Comment: Stu, what's stopping me is i don't know how to form the query obviously? if you're that interested, I've tried selecting a count(distinct column_name) greater than a certain value, but only on a singular column. there isn't a great way for me to do this to hundreds of columns.

Comment: Thanks tadman, I think that points me in the right direction.

Comment: Not specifically Postgres but [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140647/select-only-rows-with-at-least-2-non-missing-values) might be the same question?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres provides the function [num_nonnulls()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-comparison.html) which does exactly what you are looking for. Something like:

```
select * 
  from some_table 
 where num_nonnulls( col1, col2, ...) > 10;
```

There is also a corresponding `num_nulls()` function.
Yes, the downside is you must list each column name.